# How to combine 3 queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-tables

I have 3 queries that ultimately get me daily financial information.  What i'd like to do is combine the columns I need as 1 input.  I tried doing derived tables but it is extremely sloppy and didn't work.  Does anyone have any suggestion on how I can combine these 3 to give me output on 1 line?

Here are my queries:

```
SELECT        ReportCategoryID, ReportCategoryName, PrintOrder, QTY, NetAmt, customers, Average
FROM            dbo.fRevenueSummary(@startdate, @enddate) AS fRevenueSummary_1
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT        COUNT(*) AS count, SUM(TicketsDetails.dblTotal) AS Merch_Total
FROM            TicketsDetails INNER JOIN
                         Surcharges ON TicketsDetails.Reference_ID = Surcharges.Surcharge_ID INNER JOIN
                         SurchargesTypes ON Surcharges.lSurchargeTypeID = SurchargesTypes.lSurchargeTypeID
WHERE        (TicketsDetails.dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (SurchargesTypes.lSurchargeTypeID = '2') AND (TicketsDetails.bPaid = 1) AND 
                         (TicketsDetails.Detail_Type_ID = 3) AND (NOT (TicketsDetails.sDescription = N'TIP'))
```

Third Query:

```
SELECT        SUM(dblRegLabor) AS Regular_Amount, SUM(dblOTLabor) AS OT_Amount
FROM            TimeClock
WHERE        (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '1') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '2') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '3') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '4') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '5') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '6') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '7')
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the desired output and the how are the tables `TimeClock`, `TicketsDetails`, `Surcharges` and `SurchargesTypes ` are related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be like this

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT        ReportCategoryID, ReportCategoryName, PrintOrder, QTY, NetAmt, customers, Average
    FROM            dbo.fRevenueSummary(@startdate, @enddate) AS fRevenueSummary_1
)
,
(
    SELECT        COUNT(*) AS count, SUM(TicketsDetails.dblTotal) AS Merch_Total
    FROM            TicketsDetails INNER JOIN
                         Surcharges ON TicketsDetails.Reference_ID = Surcharges.Surcharge_ID INNER JOIN
                         SurchargesTypes ON Surcharges.lSurchargeTypeID = SurchargesTypes.lSurchargeTypeID
    WHERE        (TicketsDetails.dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (SurchargesTypes.lSurchargeTypeID = '2') AND (TicketsDetails.bPaid = 1) AND 
                         (TicketsDetails.Detail_Type_ID = 3) AND (NOT (TicketsDetails.sDescription = N'TIP'))
)
,
(
    SELECT        SUM(dblRegLabor) AS Regular_Amount, SUM(dblOTLabor) AS OT_Amount
    FROM            TimeClock
    WHERE        (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '1') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '2') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '3') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '4') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '5') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '6') OR
                         (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = '7')
)
```

but if there's no relation between them, you will return a Cartesian product.

I don't think there's a way to combine 3 different queries without a Cartesian product.

Comment: It's a cartesian product. I don't think there's a way to combine 3 different queries without.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer to your question,** but it may simplify your thinking to know that your third query could be greatly simplified:

```
SELECT  SUM(dblRegLabor) AS Regular_Amount, SUM(dblOTLabor) AS OT_Amount
FROM    TimeClock
WHERE   (dtTimeIn > @startdate) AND (dtTimeOut < @enddate) AND (sDept = IN('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want the ugly, messy solution, you can just put parentheses around each statement, then treat each one as a table in a giant `JOIN` (something similar to what Marc illustrates).

If you want a good solution,  you will have to describe what you are actually trying to do.  Without knowing your data and your actual task, [we can't optimize your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13511317/1584772).