# Need some ideas on optimizing this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have the query below and I am looking for ways to optimize it (etc make it more efficient and faster). Does anyone have any ideas?

```
SELECT s.oem_id, s.name, SUM(u.minimum_gfs) AS minimum_gfs, sum(u.minimum_ofs) AS    
   minimum_ofs, sum(u.minimum_wq) AS minimum_wq
FROM nmp_building_reqs AS s
   LEFT OUTER JOIN nmp_building_util AS u
ON u.oem_id = s.oem_id
GROUP BY s.oem_id, s.name
```

Comment: Have you run the query and produced an *actual* execution plan? That would be extremely helpful to get started with

Comment: Um, add indexes? Defrag?  Without more info (and an execution plan as per @marc_s) on the data you require, you can't really optimize the query itself without changing the resulting data set.  For example, the LEFT JOIN is going to be slower than an INNER JOIN, but changing that will eliminate some rows.

Comment: Please see this for writing a better question concerning optimizing SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13511317/1584772

Comment: Whats wrong with this? the query itself is as clean and simple as it gets. if its not performing well, then check your indexes on both tables

Answer (score 5):

The only obvious thing to do is to be sure that oem_id is indexed to make the join faster.

However, I have a suspicion that you can do the aggregation before the join, and then bring in the name.  This is assuming that oem_id has only one name associated with it.  The query would look like:

```
SELECT s.oem_id, s.name, u.minimum_gfs, u.minimum_ofs, u.minimum_wq
FROM nmp_building_reqs s left outer join
     (select u.oem_id, SUM(u.minimum_gfs) AS minimum_gfs,
             sum(u.minimum_ofs) AS minimum_ofs, sum(u.minimum_wq) AS minimum_wq
      from nmp_building_util u
      group by u.oem_id
     ) u
     ON u.oem_id = s.oem_id
```

Comment: The latter suggestion might work well. Surprisingly, the query optimizer never does this by itself. Not implemented, obviously.

Comment: @usr . . . There are so many things optimizers do *not* do, that it is easy to overlook the many things they *do* do.  My favorite are queries where I can build an index and run the query in way less time that just running the query.

Comment: Hmm I tried that but it's complaining that minimum_gfs is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function or GROUP BY clause

Comment: @dido . . . Sorry about that.  I meant to delete the outer `group by`.